# C# to access Database connection troubles

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and 1st post here. I'm am writing a windows form app to be used as a database entry tool. to do this I'm connecting to an access database to read lists and capture new inputs

the error I'm getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

at

```
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The code of the form that is driving the fault is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Metrics_Data
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        Welcome conndata = new Welcome();
        public Login()
        {

               InitializeComponent();  

        }

        private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Verify Password and UserID
            string Password = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from [Users] WHERE UserID = @UserID",conndata.myconn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_userid;            
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            Password = reader["User_Password"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();

            //Load Next Form
            UserHome userHomeform = new Metrics_Data.UserHome();
            this.Hide();
            userHomeform.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The code that connects from the welcome screen is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Metrics_Data
{
    public partial class Welcome : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection myconn = null;
        public Welcome()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                OleDbConnection myconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\148.96.211.237\GroupShares\Quality\Electronic Checksheets\MD.accdb;jet OLEDB:Database Password=""Warranty""");

                myconn.Open();
                lbl_Connstatus.Text = "Connected to DB";
                p_dbconn.Visible = true;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error connecting to DB");
                btn_cfg.Visible = false;
                btn_home.Visible = false;
                btn_help.Visible = true;

            }
        }

        class Variables
        {
            public static dynamic LoginType;
            public static dynamic UserID;
            public static dynamic Admin;
            public static dynamic FirstUse;
            public static dynamic Zone;
            public static dynamic Shift;
            public static dynamic Group;
            public static dynamic CDate;
            public static dynamic GateLevel;
            public static dynamic CountermeasureID;
        }

            private void Welcome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If program is unable to connect with database, initiate sequence where computer's installed access database engine's are displayed in popups, then tell user that program cannot connect
            //popups are displayed to help user. If no database engine popups are displayed, see the following URL for troubleshooting information:
            //https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2874601/can-t-use-the-access-odbc-driver-or-oledb-provider-outside-office-clic
            //A possible fix to this problem is to install access runtime 2013. The URL below has the link to where it's stored locally:
            //\\10.35.193.112\Open\AccessRuntime2013 
            //Update: This also resolves concerns for computers with MS Office 2016, in which the user will receive a popup indicating they have an OLEDB database engine, but the program still will
            //not work. IT may be required to give users temporary administrative rights to install AccessRuntime2013.
            string AccessDBAsValue = string.Empty;
            RegistryKey rkACDBKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes");
            if (rkACDBKey != null)
            {
                foreach (string subKeyName in rkACDBKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    if (subKeyName.Contains("Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(subKeyName));
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("The program was unable to connect to the database.");
        }

        private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        private void btn_home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login loginform = new Metrics_Data.Login();
            Variables.LoginType = "Data Entry";
            loginform.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here??? I have verified path to database and the connection string at initial connection does not give any errors, nor do I have any errors in the error space on visual studio.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`.

Comment: I suggest two things: 1. Open and close the connection for every command. ADO.NET is pretty smart about caching connections well. 2. Don't use classes that inherit from Form as places to put data that needs to be accessed from several places; use a separate class.

Comment: You are having two `myconn` variables in same name. One is public property and the other one is private one. Remove `OleDbConnection` in `OleDbConnection myconn = new..` line and try.

Comment: I think your connection is closed, because it's only available in the scope of your Welcome form and not your Login class.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your constructor is *hiding* the form property `myconn` with a local variable, so when you reference the form property, it will be null.

However, I'd be remiss if I did not suggest that you NOT store the connection in a form property. ADO.NET Connections are pooled and are generally cheap to create, so just create one when you need one and dispose of it (using `using`) when you're done with the query it's created for.

You can store the *connection string* in one place, but sharing connection objects is generally a bad idea.

Not using a shared connection will also make it simpler since you don't have to worry about checking if the connection is open or not, worrying about opening it twice, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I have it figured out, i stripped out the welcome screen and just reconnect each time as suggested.